# ICommand not running task

Tags: c#, wpf

I am updating a property in Viewmodel-A from Viewmodel-B while in View-B. In the same function that calls for the property update, the view is switched to View-A; The breakpoint I set on `private async Task RepopulateFieldValues` doesn't get hit.

So when I click on my button in View-B, I see all my relevant breakpoints get hit in Viewmodel-B, my view switches over to View-A, I see my breakpoint hit on the ICommand and thats it. Then, if I switch my view back to any other view, I see the breakpoint on my Tasks getting hit. I know I've got something backwards.

This is my property in Viewmodel-A thats updated via Viewmodel-B:

```
        private int _ApptSelected;
        public int ApptSelected {
            get { return _ApptSelected; }
            set {
                _ApptSelected = (MainViewModel.ApptID.Count > 0) ? MainViewModel.ApptID[0] : 0;
            }
        }
```

Here is my ICommand:

```
public ICommand RepopulateFields_Command => new AsyncRelayCommand(RepopulateFieldValues);
```

This is the only way I could come up with to trigger the `RepopulateFields_Command`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="HackProperty"
                 Text="{Binding ApptSelected,
                        Mode=OneWay,
                        NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
            <behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
                <behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RepopulateFields_Command}" />
                </behaviors:EventTrigger>
            </behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
```

And this is the "cascading" Tasks Im trying to run:

```
private async Task RepopulateFieldValues()
        {
            if (ApptSelected > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ApptSelected: " + ApptSelected);
                await RetrieveEditInfo(ApptSelected);
            }
        }
```

This is the relevant code within Viewmodel-B (for switching views)

```
public void EditSelection_Clicked(object obj)
        {
            if(Messaging.AskQuestion("Do you want to edit this appointment?"))
            {
                SelectedVM = AppointmentsViewModel.ApptTabItems[1];
                AppointmentsViewModel.ApptTabItems[1].IsSelected = true;
                ApptSelectedID = ApptIDSelected.ApptID;
                Messaging.ShowAlert("ID: " + ApptSelectedID);
                MainViewModel.ApptID.Clear();
                MainViewModel.ApptID.Add(ApptSelectedID);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you saying that `RepopulateFieldValues()` is not called, i.e. that the command is not executed? Or what do you mean? When do you expect the command to get executed...? `ApptSelected` is a read-only property by the way. It's not "updated via Viewmodel-B".

Comment: @mm8 I forgot to edit the ```ApptSelected``` to reflect a change with that. The ICommand is not being executed, I would expect it to be executed when the ```<TextBox x:Name="HackProperty">...``` is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EventTrigger` that you are using only works with routed events and `TextChanged` is not a routed event. This means that your command won't be invoked when you type something into the `TextBox`.

But if you simply want to fire-and-forget the command, you should be able to execute it directly in the setter of the `ApptSelected` which is bound to the `TextBox`:

```
public int ApptSelected {
    get { return _ApptSelected; }
    set {
         _ApptSelected = (MainViewModel.ApptID.Count > 0) ? MainViewModel.ApptID[0] : 0;
         _ = RepopulateFieldValues();
        }
    }
```

Then you don't need to bother about the `TextChanged` event at all.